# why it does not log anythings in console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

and when three cell matches happens it does not logs anythings and in my eyes it does not logs anythings because when i clicked cell there is no three matches of cells at one click, am i right

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell > img");

const win_combinations = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
];

cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
  cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.src = "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png";

    for (const [a, b, c] of win_combinations) {
      if (
        cells[a].src == "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png" &&
        cells[b].src == "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png" &&
        cells[c].src == "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png"
      ) {
        console.log(cells[a], cells[b], cells[c]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: try checking `.getAttribute("src")  == "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png"` instead

Comment: yes it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell > img");
    
    const win_combinations = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
    ];
    
    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
      cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.src = "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png";
    
        for (const [a, b, c] of win_combinations) {
          if (
            cells[a].src.includes("Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png") &&
            cells[b].src.includes("Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png") &&
            cells[c].src.includes("Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png")
          ) {
            console.log("Winning combination:", cells[a], cells[b], cells[c]);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```